# Retrieve stored values of selected restaurant from localstorage using simplecart

Tags: php, javascript, local-storage, simplecart

Im trying to retrieve the cart items stored in the local storage based on the selected restaurant.

First, in the console log it looks like the "each" loop is running twice.

Second, the indexOf is working! But the is a problem with the following two lines:

> `simpleCart.get(item).show();`
>
> AND
>
> `simpleCart.get(item).hide();`

The first one kinda seams to work but the second is compitely ignored and returns all the results from the localstorage.

How can i hide the selected item from showing in the cart???????? HELP!!!

---

**`$restName`** = the selected restaurant. (a php variable)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
simpleCart.bind(\'load\', function(){
    var items = localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items");
    if (!items) {
        return;
    } try {
        simpleCart.each(JSON.parse(items),function(item) {
            var id_found = item.itmid.indexOf("' . $restName . '");
            if (id_found >= 0){
                simpleCart.get(item).show();
            } else {
                simpleCart.get(item).hide();
            }
        });
    } catch (e){
        simpleCart.error("Error Loading data: " + e);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Err... I can't understand the question. Maybe you can single out the precisely what you want to know.

Comment: muavo thanks for your response. i have edited the question and is more clear and precise now. i hope that somebody can help me... thenx anw!

Answer (score 0):

May be providing some data example from the localStorage would help understanding the issue. BTW, have you tried retrieving that value from console?